# How to initialize annotation configuration instance in Hibernate 4?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-4.x, hibernate3

I am using `hibernate-release-4.2.4.Final` version and tried using annotations instead of the `hbm.xml` file. But while running, it always throws `an-annotation-configuration-instance-is-required-to-use-error`.

When I tried importing `org.hibernate.AnnotationConfiguration` it showed the class was deprecated.

Then I tried copying Annotation configuration class file from the `hibernate-annotation.jar` and used and it in the `hibernate3.jar` and it worked fine.

My question is how to initialize a annotation configuration instance in the newer version of Hibernate release?

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate 4 you should not use `AnnotationConfiguration` anymore, use `Configuration` instead.

Use `HibernateUtils` or other session factory builder to build the session factory.

An example of such utility you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17210804/573032).